# Error CS1503 - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'int' in ASP.NET Core GetById

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.Net Core-5 Web API for my project:

```
public interface IEmployeeService
{
    public Task<bool> DeleteEmployee(long Id);
    public bool EntityExists(long id);
}

public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public EmployeeService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _context = context;
    }
    public bool EntityExists(long id)
    {
        return _unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.EntityExists(id);
    }   
 
    public async Task<Employee> GetById(long id)
    {
        return await _unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.GetById(id);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Delete(long Id)
    {
        try
        {
            await _unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.Delete(Id);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The id for Employee is bigint, so I used long.

I got this error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'int'

and it highlights id in:

> return _unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.EntityExists(id);

> return await _unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.GetById(id);

> await _unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.Delete(Id);

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Change the parameter type on the methods that call these to `int` i.e. Int32 instead of Int64. You'll likely have to change the code where these values are passed through from `long` to `int` too.

Comment: Or you could change the called methods to handle `long`s instead

Comment: Can you share the whole Call Stack?